# undefined method `periodic' for Sidekiq:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using 'sidekiq' gem for background jobs. I wanted to add periodic (cron) job. I have add initializer names sidekiq.rb and the content of it is:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.periodic do |mgr|
   mgr.register('* * * * *', MessageLogJob)
  end
end
```

and added a class in jobs folder:

```
class MessageLogJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    # do some thing
  end
end
```

when i restart the server and run command "bundle exec sidekiq" it gives me an error "undefined method `periodic' for Sidekiq:Module"

Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: You are use the Sidekiq Enterprise edition?

Comment: Ah is there any other way to add cron job using sidekiq other than enterprise edition?

Comment: The is only two way. 1) Buy Sidekiq Enterprise edition 2) Create own extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `periodic` is part of [Sidekiq Enterprise](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs).

If you want to have cron-like jobs in Sidekiq, you can use one of multiple GEMs:

- [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron)
- [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) - no longer maintained, but personally I really liked it
- [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) - works with every queuing system

I am sure there are more plugins.